# Integrating a video youtube

Tags: css, youtube

I would like to integrate a video youtube but it doesn't work. The video is there but doesn't play automatically on my website, what could be the reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refine your question by adding what you've tried and your current code. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more. :)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube stopped autoplay support with their embed API - this may be the reason you are dissatisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube no longer supports autoplay:

Go to youtube to mp4 and convert your video to mp4:
https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/youtube-converter

Then add this html code to your website:

```
<video controls autoplay muted>
  <source src="YourVideoNameHere.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a video file solution, they asked for a youtube video